# Susy columns overflowing grid

Tags: susy

I'm just trying [susy](http://susy.oddbird.net/) for the first time, but having a bit of difficulty.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col last"></div>
</div>
```

#### SCSS

```
@import "susy"; 

$susy: (
  container: 1140px, 
  columns: 12, 
  gutters: 0.5, 
  global-box-sizing: border-box, 
  debug: (image: show-columns)
);

@include border-box-sizing;

.wrap {
  @include container;
}

.col{
  @include span(3);
  height:40px;
  background:#f00;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I think I have this right, but my columns are coming out outside of the grid:

[image]

You can see the code running here: http://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/Ejjxwv

How do I get the columns exactly inside the grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your columns are actually correct, and the background gradient is wrong. It's a browser bug. See the [documentation](http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/toolkit/#show-grid).